# React wrapper with Routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

have wrapped my Route with Routes but it keeps showing me error that it needs to be wrapped in Routes

here is the exact error from my console
react-router-dom.js?v=74614133:209 Uncaught Error: A <Route> is only ever to be used as the child of <Routes> element, never rendered directly. Please wrap your <Route> in a <Routes>

below is my actual code

```
 <Routes>
          <Route
            path={ROUTES.LOGIN}
            element={
              <IsUserLoggedIn user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} navigate={Navigate}>
                <Route index element={<Login />} />
              </IsUserLoggedIn>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path={ROUTES.SIGN_UP}
            element={
              <IsUserLoggedIn user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} navigate={Navigate}>
                <Route index element={<Signup />} />
              </IsUserLoggedIn>
            }
          />
          <Route path={ROUTES.PROFILE} element={<Profile />} />
          <Route
            path={ROUTES.DASHBOARD}
            element={
              <ProtectedRoute user={user} navigate={Navigate}>
                <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
              </ProtectedRoute>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </Router>
here was what i tried and it is supposed to run
```

Comment: Hello , could you please provide the entire code from the file?

Comment: okay let me do just that

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is about the nested `Route` Component in the `Route`:

```
<Route index element={<Login />} /> <-- this one should be also a direct child of a `Routes` Component.
```

I am not sure 100% about what you are trying to do but I would suggest something different:

```
  <Route
    path={ROUTES.LOGIN}
    element={
      <IsUserLoggedIn user={user} loggedInPath={ROUTES.DASHBOARD} navigate={Navigate}>
        <Login />
      </IsUserLoggedIn>
    }
  />
```

Do you think it makes sense for you?

Comment: did this exact thing but it is still asking me to wrap it in routes@Prince Sadariya